# Software Updater

Tags: 14.04, update-manager

I had run Software Updater and got the message "**the software on this computer is up to date**" when my laptop was connected to internet but it displayed updates available for Ubuntu when my laptop was not connected to internet. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If the problem persists try the auto-remove switch